# mongoid / mongodb - Geospatial queries on embedded document

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

it is possible to do a geospatial query on the embedded document and have a "flat" results?

```
Class a
  ....
  embeds_many : bs
end


Class b
   ....
   field :location, :type => Array

   embedded_in :a, :inverse_of => :b
   index [[:location, Mongo::GEO2D]]
end
```

I was able to push the indexation in the mongo console

```
db.a.ensureIndex({"bs.location" : "2d"})
```

And then was able to query from the mongo console

```
db.a.find( { 'b.location' : { $near : [50,50] } # mongo console
```

However, the results is a list of "a" Documents, and not a list of "b" objects.

Two question:
1* It is what I am trying to do doable? (I know [and follow the virtual collection Jira] http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-142)

2* If yes, how can it be accomplished in Mongoid?

If not, the only option I will have will be to remove the embedded collection and move to a "classic" reference / is_referenced couple of classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in v2.0, but is in v2.1, using the aggregation framework and renaming fields (there may be other ways too).

The basic idea is to $match : { $near : <> }, then $project : { _id : 0, location : "$b.location" }

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework+-+%24project#AggregationFramework-%24project-RenamingFields

Comment: thanks. Look promising. Might just wait for the 2.1 to check this out and / or to to a classic reference for the time being if I cannot wait until then.

Answer (score 0):

It's not doable. You will have to use one query to get a list of "a" documents then filter it down into a list of "b" documents, but there is no way to merge that into one step.